# evt.offsetX returns undefined on Safari

Tags: javascript, svg, mobile-safari, touchstart

I am trying to implement a drag/move action on an SVG element using Javascript. I am using event handlers such as this:

```
function handleMouseDown(evt) {
            currentX = evt.offsetX;
            currentY = evt.offsetY;
            dX = currentX - Number($(evt.srcElement).attr("x"));
            dY = currentY - Number($(evt.srcElement).attr("y"));
            isDragging = true;
            $info.html("mousedown at " + currentX + ", " + currentY); //feedback for debugging
        }
```

Note that I already have code to point either mousedown or touchstart to handleMouseDown, depending on whether it is a touch device or not.

On my desktop, the code works fine on IE9, Google and Safari. However on an iPad, on touchstart, the feedback shows "mousedown at undefined, undefined." If I replace .offsetX and .offsetY with .pageX and .pageY, then I get actual coordinates. So it seems Safari Mobile does not handle .offsetX and .offsetY, but it does handle .pageX and .pageY.

I know that I can calculate .offsetX from pageX using the source elements position.left property, but I would like to avoid this if possible. SO MY QUESTION IS: is there something wrong in my code or approach, or is .offsetX not handled in Safari Mobile.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clientX` and `clientY` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Was having similar issue on binding event-handler using jQuery's `.on` function on `canvas` element (Don't know the reason).

I resolved it by binding event-handler using `addEventListener`. The `event` object in the handler has offsetX and offsetY defined with proper values.

Hope it helps...